# EF core Get Count and sum in one call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework core, can I get the total sum of the column and row count in one call?
I have the following code, but I think there is a better way to do this.

```cs
TotalCostResponse result = new TotalCostResponse
{
    TotalCost = await dbContext.Transaction
        .Where(x => x.UserName == request.UserName
            && x.Date >= request.StartDate
            && x.Date <= request.EndDate)
        .SumAsync(x => x.Amount),

    TotalNumber = await dbContext.Transaction
        .Where(x => x.UserName == request.UserName
            && x.Date = request.StartDate
            && x.Date <= request.EndDate)
        .CountAsync()
};
```

So instead of calling dbContext two times, I need to make it in one call.

Comment: Not as your query stands right now. `TotalCost` uses `x.Date >= request.StartDate`, while `TotalNumber` uses `x.Date = request.StartDate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = await dbContext.Transaction
    .Where(x => x.UserName == request.UserName
        && x.Date >= request.StartDate
        && x.Date <= request.EndDate)
    .GroupBy(x => 1)
    .Select(group => new TotalCostResponse
    {
        TotalCost = group.Sum(x => x.Amount),
        TotalNumber = group.Count()
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with one query, there are certainly other ways that you can find.

```
// In the select get only what you need, in your case only the amount
var transactions = 
    await this.dbContext.Transaction
              .Where(x => x.UserName == request.UserName
                     && x.Date >= request.StartDate
                     && x.Date <= request.EndDate)
              .Select(y => new
                           {
                               Amount = y.Amount,
                           }).ToListAsync();

// Calculating the data
var result = new TotalCostResponse
                 {
                     TotalCost = transactions.Sum(x => x),
                     TotalNumber = transactions.Count(),
                 }
```